# libnetwork: Error: unknown command "/var/run/docker/netns/582bd184e561" for "some_app"

Tags: go

I am trying to setup a network in the container (using Docker's `libnetwork` and `libcontainer`), but I keep running into this issue. As far as I can tell it's looking into `some_app` to get some sandbox information?

```
INFO[3808] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4] 
INFO[3808] IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers : [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844] 
Error: unknown command "/var/run/docker/netns/582bd184e561" for "some_app"
Run 'some_app --help' for usage.
ERRO[3808] Resolver Setup/Start failed for container 6b81802576bd4f16aa117061f81b5c3e, "setup not done yet" 
ERRO[3808] failed to add interface vethef0a693 to sandbox: failed in prefunc: failed to set namespace on link "vethef0a693": invalid argument 
ERRO[3808] failed to add interface vethef0a693 to sandbox: failed in prefunc: failed to set namespace on link "vethef0a693": invalid argument
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me make sense of this and perhaps prevent it. Are these two separate errors?

Thank you

[Here is the library I am trying to use](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, but here goes:

Just like in Docker, `libnetwork` creates a veth interface pair. It then moves one end of the veth pair into the container namespace. During this process `libnetwork` tries to execute commands registered at runtime on the current instance of the binary (`some_app` in this case).

These commands do not exist on the external interface of `some_app` however. They are injected later using a library called [`reexec`](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/pkg/reexec). For this to work, `reexec` needs to be initialized like this:

```
if reexec.Init() {
    return
}
```

Also note that according to [this thread](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/971) `libnetwork` is currently not supported for applications outside of Docker.

**NB**: I discovered this by reading the source code, so I might be wrong but my issue went away after this.